# Tailwind CLI's --watch not working properly

Tags: tailwind-css

Each time I add a new class to the `index.html` file, I need to rebuild the `output.css` file manually.

The package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "tailwind-practice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tailwindcss --watch -i ./input.css -o ./output.css"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.7"
  }
}
```

The tailwind.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  screens: {
    'sm': '480px',
    'md': '768px',
    'lg': '1440px',
  },
  content: ['./index.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I am supposed to run `npm run build` once, and each time I saved the html file, tailwind is supposed to add my new classes to `output.css`. But it doesn't. I checked the file after saving `index.html` and I couldn't find my new classes there. But the CLI shamelessly said it rebuilt it in 20ms. I needed to run `npm run build` each time to successfully build my css file. Also, I deleted my previous nodejs installation and reinstalled the current version, updated VS Code, updated Google Chrome, and now, I am considering moving back to Windows from Manjaro.

**Edit**: A useful observation.

After saving `index.html`, the CLI said this:

```
Rebuilding...
Done in 27ms.
```

But when I stopped the process and reran `npm run build`, it said:

```
Rebuilding...
Done in 198ms.
```

There is a relatively huge time delay when it actually works.

**Edit 2:**

It works when I save `index.html` multiple times rapidly.

I moved from Manjaro to Ubuntu, and it still doesn't work!

Comment: Is your index.html file located in the same directory as your tailwind.config.js and package.json files? If not, it might be failing to find the file you changed. You might also verify you're changing the file and your changes are being successfully made. Many editors which autosave only do so when you defocus the editor.

Comment: What does your index.html look like?

Comment: @tauzN I don't think it has anything to do with incorrect file paths or using tailwind classes that aren't imported in the `input.css` file. In fact, everything works just fine, except for the `--watch` mode. I've figured out some ways to hack it, but they are a hassle.

Comment: @MostafizurRahman I have the same issue, you get it resolved?  What hacks are you using?

Comment: @dove Hack 1: Don't use the --watch mode. Hack 2: Run a bash script that executes `npx tailwindcss --watch -i ./input.css -o ./output.css` whenever you save the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 3):

try changing

from

```
npx tailwindcss --watch -i ./input.css -o ./output.css
```

to

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./output.css --watch
```

Comment: can you explain why ?

Comment: Hypothetically both are same. But I'm curious about your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these to your input.css to make the `--watch` work properly.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Without these, TW won't know from where it should pull info for your CSS classes and write a processed version in output.css

Let's say you wrote `<h1 class="underline">Hello world! </h1>` in `index.html`.
Tw needs to look for information on how it can parse + process the `underline` class and what should be written in output.css regarding this class.

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: This was the problem in my case, thank you!

Comment: still not working in my case